# Getting CRAZY with ComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have a data bound `ComboBox` that looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ComboBoxEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedItem}" Width="250">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<Label Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="4" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Content="No process instances have been found." Height="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeightKey}}" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="{Binding Path=WatermarkVisibility}" Width="250"/>
<Button Canvas.Right="5" Canvas.Top="5" Click="ClickRefresh" Content="Refresh" Width="75"/>
```

Then, in my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = m_ViewModel = new ViewModel();
}

private void ClickRefresh(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_ViewModel.Populate();
}
```

Here is my ViewModel.cs:

```
public ProcessInstance SelectedItem
{
    get { return m_SelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (m_SelectedItem != value)
        {
            m_SelectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<ProcessInstance> Items
{
    get { return m_Items; }
    private set
    {
        if (m_Items != value)
        {
            m_Items = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}

public ViewModel()
{
    Populate();
}

public void Populate()
{
    ProcessInstance selectedItem = m_SelectedItem;

    SelectedItem = null;
    Items = null;

    List<ProcessInstance> processInstances = new List<ProcessInstance>();

    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (...)
            processInstances.Add(new ProcessInstance(process));
    }

    if (processInstances.Count == 0)
    {
        ComboBoxEnabled = false;
        WatermarkVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ProcessInstance>(processInstances.OrderBy(x => x.Process.Id));

        if (selectedItem != null)
            SelectedItem = m_Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProcessEquals(selectedItem));

        if (m_SelectedItem == null)
            SelectedItem = m_Items[0];

        ComboBoxEnabled = true;
        WatermarkVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

And here is my ProcessInstance class relevant code:

```
public override Boolean Equals(Object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as ProcessInstance);
}

public override Int32 GetHashCode()
{
    Int32 hashCode;

    if ((m_Process == null) || m_Process.HasExited)
        hashCode = 0;
    else
    {
        hashCode = (m_Process.Id.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ m_Process.MainModule.BaseAddress.GetHashCode();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Process.MainWindowTitle))
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ m_Process.MainWindowTitle.GetHashCode();
    }

    return hashCode;
}

public override String ToString()
{
    String processId = process.Id.ToString("X8", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    String windowTitle = (process.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0) ? process.MainWindowTitle : "NULL";

    return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "[{0}] {1} - {2}", type, processId, windowTitle);
}

public Boolean Equals(ProcessInstance other)
{
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        return true;

    if (m_Process == null)
    {
        if (other.Process == null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    if (other.Process == null)
        return false;

    return ((m_Process.Id == other.Process.Id) && (m_Process.MainModule.BaseAddress == other.Process.MainModule.BaseAddress) && (m_Process.MainWindowTitle == other.Process.MainWindowTitle));
}

public Boolean ProcessEquals(ProcessInstance other)
{
    if (other == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("other");

    if (m_Process == null)
        return (other.Process == null);

    if (other.Process == null)
        return false;

    return ((m_Process.Id == other.Process.Id) && (m_Process.MainModule.BaseAddress == other.Process.MainModule.BaseAddress));
}
```

Now here is what happens... I start the application while no process instances exist:

[image]

Then I open one or more process instances and I click the Refresh button. The first one is selected by ComboBox as default... I can keep that one selected or select another one, it doesn't matter:

[image]

Now i close every process instance and I click Refresh button again. What happens in this case is that the Populate() method sets both SelectedItem and Items to null, so the ComboBox looks empty, and then it disables the ComboBox and makes the watermark Label visible. But here is what I get:

[image]

The previous SelectedItem is still there. Why? WHY?!?!

**[EDIT] HERE IS A LINK TO DOWNLOAD THE PROJECT:**

http://www.filedropper.com/damncb

Comment: where does the text 'no process instances have been found' get set ?

Comment: In XAML, Label Content="No process instances have been found."

Comment: `WatermarkVisibility` does NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes Henk, as you can see, after a Refresh with instances found, it's no more visible.

Comment: Don´t know whats going wrong but i would not set `Items` to null. Instead i would call `Clear()` on the collection.

Comment: I tried replacing null with a Clear() call (checking if Items is not null before)... still doesn't work.

Comment: If you set `Items` to a blank collection instead of `null`, does it still behave the same way?

Comment: Yes madam! Still getting that odd result!

Comment: I attached my project source code if you want to give it a try. It has beel slightly modified but the bug still remains.

Comment: @Zarathos I'm unable to run your test project because of the version, but I copied the ViewModel and XAML to a new test project and it all seems to work as expected, with the selected item being cleared, combobox disabling, and watermark appearing. I'm using VS2010, .Net 4.0, and Windows 7. What kind of setup do you have?

Comment: Net 4.5. That's why maybe?

Comment: And VS2012 of course!

Comment: Rachel, can you upload somewhere your results?

Comment: @Zarathos I've posted it as an answer below. Try and copy/paste that to a new project (shouldn't need any other resources than what's posted there), and see if the same behavior occurs. Also, if you type `@Rachel` it will notify me when you reply to me in comments here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to run your test project because of the version, but I copied the `ViewModel` class and XAML to a new test project and it all seems to work as expected, with the selected item being cleared, combobox disabling, and watermark appearing when the button is clicked.

So I would guess that either something in your environment is affecting it, or it is something else that isn't immediately apparent with your code.

To find out which, I have posted the (correctly working) code that I am using to test below.

If this doesn't work, then the problem has something to do with your environment. I'm using VS2010, .Net 4.0, and Windows 7.

If it does, then you must have something occurring elsewhere in your code that is not immediately apparent in your test examples. I would check for any async code to see if the PropertyChange notifications are occurring on a background thread, as sometimes that doesn't trigger the update on the UI thread.

I apologize in advance for the resulting code dump :)

The `ViewModel` class was copied from test project, and a find/replace done to change `"BrowserInstance"` to "ViewModelBase" to fit my testing app. Some unnecessary sections were also commented out or modified slightly to accommodate my test app.

```
public sealed class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Members: Fields
    private Boolean m_ButtonAttachEnabled;
    private Boolean m_ButtonDetachEnabled;
    private Boolean m_ButtonRefreshEnabled;
    private Boolean m_ComboBoxEnabled;
    private Boolean m_ProgressBarEnabled;
    private ViewModelBase m_SelectedItem;
    private Dictionary<String, PropertyChangedEventArgs> m_PropertyChangedEventArgs = new Dictionary<String, PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
    private Double m_ProgressBarMaximum;
    private Double m_ProgressBarValue;
    private IntPtr m_ProcessHandle;
    private IntPtr m_ProcessHook;
    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> m_Items;
    private Visibility m_WatermarkVisibility;
    #endregion

    #region Members: INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public Boolean ButtonAttachEnabled
    {
        get { return m_ButtonAttachEnabled; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_ButtonAttachEnabled != value)
            {
                m_ButtonAttachEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonAttachEnabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean ButtonDetachEnabled
    {
        get { return m_ButtonDetachEnabled; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_ButtonDetachEnabled != value)
            {
                m_ButtonDetachEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonDetachEnabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean ButtonRefreshEnabled
    {
        get { return m_ButtonRefreshEnabled; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_ButtonRefreshEnabled != value)
            {
                m_ButtonRefreshEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonRefreshEnabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean ComboBoxEnabled
    {
        get { return m_ComboBoxEnabled; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_ComboBoxEnabled != value)
            {
                m_ComboBoxEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboBoxEnabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public Boolean ProgressBarEnabled
    {
        get { return m_ProgressBarEnabled; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_ProgressBarEnabled != value)
            {
                m_ProgressBarEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgressBarEnabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase SelectedItem
    {
        get { return m_SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (m_SelectedItem != value)
            {
                m_SelectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }

    public Double ProgressBarMaximum
    {
        get { return m_ProgressBarMaximum; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_ProgressBarMaximum != value)
            {
                m_ProgressBarMaximum = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgressBarMaximum");
            }
        }
    }

    public Double ProgressBarValue
    {
        get { return m_ProgressBarValue; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_ProgressBarValue != value)
            {
                m_ProgressBarValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgressBarValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Items
    {
        get { return m_Items; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_Items != value)
            {
                m_Items = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }
    }

    public Visibility WatermarkVisibility
    {
        get { return m_WatermarkVisibility; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_WatermarkVisibility != value)
            {
                m_WatermarkVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("WatermarkVisibility");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ViewModel()
    {
        m_PropertyChangedEventArgs = new Dictionary<String, PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
        Populate();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods: Functions
    private PropertyChangedEventArgs GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs;

        if (!m_PropertyChangedEventArgs.TryGetValue(propertyName, out propertyChangedEventArgs))
            m_PropertyChangedEventArgs[propertyName] = propertyChangedEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);

        return propertyChangedEventArgs;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void ResetProgressBar(Int32 maximumValue = 100)
    {
        ProgressBarMaximum = maximumValue;
        ProgressBarValue = 0;
    }

    private void SetInterfaceStatus(Status status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case Status.Attached:
                {
                    ButtonAttachEnabled = false;
                    ButtonDetachEnabled = true;
                    ButtonRefreshEnabled = false;
                    ComboBoxEnabled = false;
                    ProgressBarEnabled = false;
                    WatermarkVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                    break;
                }

            case Status.Busy:
                {
                    ButtonAttachEnabled = false;
                    ButtonDetachEnabled = false;
                    ButtonRefreshEnabled = false;
                    ComboBoxEnabled = false;
                    ProgressBarEnabled = true;
                    WatermarkVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                    break;
                }

            case Status.Detached:
                {
                    ButtonAttachEnabled = true;
                    ButtonDetachEnabled = false;
                    ButtonRefreshEnabled = true;
                    ComboBoxEnabled = true;
                    ProgressBarEnabled = true;
                    WatermarkVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                    goto default;
                }

            case Status.DetachedEmpty:
                {
                    ButtonAttachEnabled = false;
                    ButtonDetachEnabled = false;
                    ButtonRefreshEnabled = true;
                    ComboBoxEnabled = false;
                    ProgressBarEnabled = false;
                    WatermarkVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

                    goto default;
                }

            default:
                ResetProgressBar();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Attach()
    {
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
    }

    public void Populate()
    {
        ViewModelBase selectedItem = m_SelectedItem;

        SelectedItem = null;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();

        List<ViewModelBase> ViewModelBases = new List<ViewModelBase>();

        if (selectedItem == null)
        {
            ViewModelBases.Add(new Test { TestValue = "123456789", TestEnum = TestEnum.A, TestBool = false, TestBool2 = true });
            ViewModelBases.Add(new Test { TestValue = "987365321", TestEnum = TestEnum.B, TestBool = true, TestBool2 = true });
            ViewModelBases.Add(new Test { TestValue = "784512457", TestEnum = TestEnum.B, TestBool = true, TestBool2 = true });
        }

        //foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
        //{
        //    if ((process.ProcessName == "chrome") && !process.HasExited && (process.MainModule.ModuleName == "chrome.exe"))
        //        ViewModelBases.Add(new ViewModelBase(ViewModelBaseType.Chrome, process));
        //}

        if (ViewModelBases.Count == 0)
            SetInterfaceStatus(Status.DetachedEmpty);
        else
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>(ViewModelBases);

            if (selectedItem != null)
                SelectedItem = m_Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Equals(selectedItem));

            if (m_SelectedItem == null)
                SelectedItem = m_Items[0];

            SetInterfaceStatus(Status.Detached);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Enumerators
    private enum Status
    {
        Attached,
        Busy,
        Detached,
        DetachedEmpty
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The `ViewModelBase` class from my test app looks like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // Fields
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;

    // Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler2;
            PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.propertyChanged;
            do
            {
                handler2 = propertyChanged;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler3 = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(handler2, value);
                propertyChanged = Interlocked.CompareExchange<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(ref this.propertyChanged, handler3, handler2);
            }
            while (propertyChanged != handler2);
        }
        remove
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler2;
            PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.propertyChanged;
            do
            {
                handler2 = propertyChanged;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler3 = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(handler2, value);
                propertyChanged = Interlocked.CompareExchange<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(ref this.propertyChanged, handler3, handler2);
            }
            while (propertyChanged != handler2);
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (propertyNames == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyNames");
        }
        foreach (string str in propertyNames)
        {
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(str);
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        string propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName<T>(propertyExpression);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.propertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo & Validation Members

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Property Names that should be validated
    /// </summary>
    //protected List<string> ValidatedProperties = new List<string>();


    #region Validation Delegate

    public delegate string ValidationDelegate(
        object sender, string propertyName);

    private List<ValidationDelegate> _validationDelegates =
        new List<ValidationDelegate>();

    public void AddValidationDelegate(ValidationDelegate func)
    {
        _validationDelegates.Add(func);
    }

    public void RemoveValidationDelegate(ValidationDelegate func)
    {
        if (_validationDelegates.Contains(func))
            _validationDelegates.Remove(func);
    }

    #endregion // Validation Delegate


    public virtual string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
    {
        // If user specified properties to validate, check to see if this one exists in the list
        //if (ValidatedProperties.IndexOf(propertyName) < 0)
        //{
        //    return null;
        //}

        string s = null;

        //switch (propertyName)
        //{

        //}

        foreach (var func in _validationDelegates)
        {
            s = func(this, propertyName);
            if (s != null)
                return s;
        }


        return s;
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return null; } }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
    }

    //public bool IsValid
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return (GetValidationError() == null);
    //    }
    //}

    //public string GetValidationError()
    //{
    //    string error = null;

    //    if (ValidatedProperties != null)
    //    {
    //        foreach (string s in ValidatedProperties)
    //        {
    //            error = GetValidationError(s);
    //            if (error != null)
    //            {
    //                return error;
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }

    //    return error;
    //}

    #endregion // IDataErrorInfo & Validation Members
}
```

And the `Test` class for testing is this:

```
public class Test : ViewModelBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private TestEnum _testEnum;
    private string _testValue = "Testing";
    private double _testNumber = 10000;
    private bool _testBool;
    private bool _testBool2;

    private ObservableCollection<int> _someCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<int> SomeCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_someCollection == null)
                _someCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();

            return _someCollection;
        }
    }

    public Test()
    {
        //this.ValidatedProperties.Add("TestValue");
        //this.ValidatedProperties.Add("TestNumber");

        SomeCollection.Add(1);
        SomeCollection.Add(2);
        SomeCollection.Add(3);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TestValue;
    }


    public void RaisePropertyChanged1(string property)
    {
        base.RaisePropertyChanged(property);
    }

    //public override string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
    //{

    //    // If user specified properties to validate, check to see if this one exists in the list
    //    if (ValidatedProperties.IndexOf(propertyName) < 0)
    //    {
    //        return null;
    //    }

    //    string s = base.GetValidationError(propertyName); ;

    //    switch (propertyName)
    //    {
    //        case "TestValue":
    //            s = "error";
    //            break;
    //    }

    //    return s;

    //}



    public TestEnum TestEnum
    {
        get { return _testEnum; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _testEnum)
            {
                _testEnum = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TestEnum);
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<int> _test;

    public ObservableCollection<int> Test1
    {
        get
        {
            if (_test == null)
            {
                _test = new ObservableCollection<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    _test.Add(i);
                }
            }
            return _test;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _test)
            {
                _test = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Test1);
            }
        }
    }

    public string TestValue
    {
        get { return _testValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _testValue)
            {
                _testValue = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TestValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TestBool
    {
        get { return _testBool; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _testBool)
            {
                _testBool = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TestBool);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TestBool2
    {
        get { return _testBool2; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _testBool2)
            {
                _testBool2 = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TestBool);
            }
        }
    }

    public double TestNumber
    {
        get { return _testNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _testNumber)
            {
                _testNumber = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TestNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test XAML was looked like this. I had added a min-height because it wasn't showing up correctly with my test styles, and a background color was added just to see where it was rendering at.

```
<Grid MinHeight="100" Background="Lavender">
    <Canvas Background="Red">
        <GroupBox Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="5" BorderBrush="Black" Header="Test" Height="86" Width="472">
            <Canvas>
                <ComboBox Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ComboBoxEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedItem}" Width="366">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Text="{Binding }" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
                <Label Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="4" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Content="This is a Test" Height="50" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="{Binding Path=WatermarkVisibility}" Width="366"/>
                <Button Canvas.Right="5" Canvas.Top="5" Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Refresh" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ButtonRefreshEnabled}" Width="75"/>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

And last of all, the code behind my XAML:

```
ViewModel m_ViewModel;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = m_ViewModel = new ViewModel();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_ViewModel.Populate();
}
```

Comment: I'm having hard times here understanding what you changed and what changed in the global behavior. Anyway, I'll test it soon! Many thanks!

Comment: @Zarathos Let me know how it goes, I'm curious about it :) For your test project, I pretty much copy/pasted the `ViewModel` class and the XAML (including code-behind) into my test project, and then modified them slightly to change/comment out parts that seemed unrelated to the problem and that referenced other areas of your application. The `ViewModelBase` and `Test` class already existed in my test project, so I just substituted that for the `BrowserInstance` class. I didn't look at any of the other files in your test app.

Comment: Ok your implementation worked... then I found the way to fix mine based on some debug log... it was a bad implementation of BrowserInstance IEquatable which, for some reason, doesn't raise up in bad behavior in your project!

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear the `SelectedValue` property on the `ComboBox`, or maybe set `SelectedIndex` to -1

Comment: So I have to bind that property too?

Comment: You mean I should replace SelectedItem binding with a TwoWay SelectedValue?

Comment: It doesn't work :(
I attached my project source code if you want to give it a try. It has beel slightly modified but the bug still remains.

Comment: Not working. It's incredible. It looks like something is setting SelectedItem back to it's previous value after I null it. Could this have something to do with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing your `ObservableCollection`.  Try this  :

```
if (processInstances.Count == 0)
{
    Items.Clear();

    // remaining of your logic;
}
```

Comment: I don't clear it, but i set it to null at the beginning of ViewModel.Populate() method. I tried, anyway, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I attached my project source code if you want to give it a try. It has beel slightly modified but the bug still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Few points to hit the solution

1. Try clearing the values instead of nullifying them, so that WPF UI elements would not loose the binding to the instance when `PropertyChanged` events are triggered..
2. Based on point 1, Set the `SelectedItem` internals to value '' for the `Text` property or whatsoever you have wrapped instead of nullifying entire instance and recreating new each time.
3. Hmm.. You have not shown how the `combobox.selectedItem` is getting the `ToString()` or something similar from the wrapper class `ProcessInstance` of your so I could not post the change of logic from code perspective.

Comment: I added the override ToString() of my ProcessInstance editing my question. I don't get the second point though...

Comment: ok I guess you could null the internal _process object and `ToString()` should return '' when _process is null..

Comment: Tryed... but even if ComboBox is empty, a SelectedItem is still there, and it's not null. I attached my project source code if you want to give it a try. It has beel slightly modified but the bug still remains.

Comment: ok I will try this tonight and revert back. As of now I don't have VS for WPF handy..